# Is there any xml parser other than BS4 and LXML in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

Is there any xml parser other than BS4 and LXML that I can use?

I cannot pip install BS4 and LXML in the environment I am in, but I would need to do some simple xml parsing - getting node by id or name, get or set attribute values of a node and etc.

Is there any other library that I can use?

Comment: I disagree with the votes to close. This isn't asking for a general tool question like "LOL I don't like to read and want to know what web framework to use", but asking for specific information about a standard Python installation.

Comment: I was going to answer this: there are several [built-in XML parsers](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.html). In particular, [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) may be useful in your situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I will try your suggestion.  I agree with you about closing this question.

Comment: @Kirk Strauser, I find xml.etree.ElementTree quite capable with proper use of XPath.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome! Happy hacking, @Kay! 

Comment: @Kirk Strauser, is there html parser that I can use for similar purpose?  I tried html.parser, but is very different.  I just need to get nodes by id or names, get or set attribute values of a node and etc.

Comment: Sorry, @Kay: that's the only one I know of that's likely to be available in your setup. You could probably _get_ values using regular expressions or string matching as long as the input HTML is reasonably consistent, but I don't know of anything built-in that would let you easily modify the document.

Comment: @Kay Recommend you a simple library: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples/get_element.py

Comment: @dabingsou, Thank you so much for the recommendation.  I am trying it right now.

Comment: Thank you guys all for helping through this closed question.  I really appreciate your recommendations and suggestions.